# is it possible to call a Google publish API with json service account?

Tags: api, curl, google-play

There is an API.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.deobfuscationfiles/upload

```
POST https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits/{editId}/apks/{apkVersionCode}/deobfuscationFiles/{deobfuscationFileType}
```

Also example with curl:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[PACKAGENAME]/edits/[EDITID]/apks/[APKVERSIONCODE]/deobfuscationFiles/[DEOBFUSCATIONFILETYPE]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And there is **service-api-account.json**

How to call API with service json account?